# After a line of dialogue, if an action is taking that does not change the POV but slightly alters it be a new paragraph or be in the same one?

Tags: creative-writing, fantasy

what I mean by altering the path is like from this context to: we walked to her house

Here is the context:

> "Let's go to your house." I said
>
> "Ok." she mumbled down looking at the floor. we walked to her house

or would it be

> "Ok." she mumbled looking down at the floor.
>
> We walked over to her house

Comment: Your lines of dialogue should end with commas, not full stops :)

Answer (score 2):

### What you are describing is not a POV shift, but signals the focus of the POV character’s attention.

How to handle shifts in focus to produce a better story is a complex topic. I’ve never read anyone’s discussions on the subject, nor seen any listings of the strengths and weaknesses of different approaches.

Your two examples have subtly implied differences because of that paragraph break.  Even though they have identical wording, that new paragraph creates a small twist in cause and effect leaves room for interpretation why the events in the previous paragraph lead to the events in this new paragraph.

There might also be an implied pause between the two talking and walking.

I think that its about the subtle effects the author wants to create in their story, when to chose to start a new paragraph when the actions might fit in one paragraph without loss of clarity or readability